# Load all localization resources on startup

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, localization, internationalization

I've found a few similar topics, but I didn't get the answer I'm looking for.

I'm just trying the internationalization before I commence a "more serious" (WinForms) project. So, currently in my small test application, I solved the localization using satellite assemblies (language dll files), and I fill the controls' text fields with ResourceManager, and the language change is resolved by Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture & Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture methods.

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(lang);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

this.button1.Text = Resources.LocTest.String1;
```

I would like to load all texts from the resources on the program initial startup, not only the main form but all of them (also on those forms, that not instantiated yet)!
How could I implement this? Is this procedure is feasible at all?

I got some advice that I should simplify the whole localization process, by setting the "localizable" property to true and make the translations done.
And most of the tutorials follow this way.

Does anybody have any idea, which method should I use?

Thanks in advance!

I'm very confused with the localization...

Comment: Basically, you should always follow best practices and do not try to reinvent the wheel (how boring). Therefore it is a good idea to use standard approach, that is switch Localizable to true and let Visual Studio to care for creating Resource Managers and other stuff. You also **should not** assign thread cultures, that should be assigned automatically, otherwise built-in fall-back mechanism won't work.

Comment: As for loading resources, everything is possible for those who try. The only question is why in the world you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understood that you wrote ("do not try to reinvent the wheel")! I try to follow the best practices. Actually, the only reason I wanted to use this resource dll version, that user must restart the application when change the language...

Comment: Yes, the user would have to restart the application when language changes. But it is only the case when you implement language switching functionality in your app, which is common anti-pattern. You should try to detect the language from the OS (in fact Winforms will do that automatically for you) and display the texts based on CurrentUICulture property. If user want to see UI in another language, (s)he can switch appropriate setting in Regional & Language option. 
That's it.

Comment: language selection is an anti-pattern? I'm a french speaker unsing a french Windows UI. This app I just installed supports German and English only. According to you, I should change a language setting in control panel to tell this specific app to display in German rather than in English. Actually, I should change my Windows UI language if I want the app to follow it. 1st, this requires a logout/login, 2nd, German Windows UI may not be installed, 3rd I'll end up with Windows (and all other apps) in German only because of this specific app which doesn't support French. You're kidding, right?

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator I'd sort of agree with both of you. That the OS doesn't let you give a prioritised list of locales so that the app can automatically go "French? Sorry, Okay German, yeah I can do that?" is a flaw. That the app decides it knows best what language to use is an anti-pattern, but the flaw requires its use.

Comment: I don't quite understand why we shouldn't give users the ability to select their favorite language. Of course we should do our best to anticipate the choice so that user immediately sees the UI in her favorite language. But there are obviously cases where we can't guess. In those cases, what else besides letting user choose?

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator I can't find it now but I sort of remember seeing a Microsoft tool that allows you to launch an application in a language of your choice (maybe it also set a codepage of your choice... I think I saw that years ago before Unicode was standard). Rather than each application implementing their own language selection and clogging their UI, it really ought to be an OS thing, as per Pawel and Jon's comments.

Comment: You probably have AppLocale in mind. This is a test tool aimed at simulating the Regional Settings language for non-unicode programs. This is definetely a testing tool and not one users are supposed to use.

Answer (score 2):

please use the second method you've mentioned.

> I got some advice that I should simplify the whole localization process, by setting the "localizable" property to true and make the translations done. And most of the tutorials follow this way.

Because this is the intended way of how Microsoft think localization should be done in a winforms app. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

One problem with your first solution: **How do you maintain that a text in another language will be displayed correctly?**

That's one of the occuring problems, Microsoft have been aware of. With a small tool found in the SDK called: WINRES.exe you can see the designed forms and write the translation for them.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bxdx003%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

If you want to change the language on runtime and update all forms this article maybe a hint for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163609.aspx#S9
The following lines gives an explain howto update you UI:

```
Dim crm As ComponentResourceManager  
crm = New ComponentResourceManager(GetType(Main))   
crm.ApplyResources(cmdAddCustomer, cmdAddCustomer.Name)   
crm.ApplyResources(mnuFile, mnuFile.Name)   
crm.ApplyResources(mnuFileAddCustomer, mnuFileAddCustomer.Name)
```

The last 3 lines of this code can be found in each form (localizable = true) in the designer file.
So you can specify an interface for an update method, which every form should implement, implement the interface and after language change iterate the through all forms and call these method.

Hope this might help you ...